# ActiveRecord Query: Get Distinct Users from Posts in Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

(Rails 4.1.6, Ruby 2.0.0)

I have a collection of **users** that have made a series of **posts** in **categories**. The posts **have and belong to many** **categories**. I wanted to fetch a list of users that have posted in that **category**. Searching StackOverflow, I found something that works for a single **category**.

```
Category.find(2).posts.select(:user_id).distinct
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work when I merge categories (both categories exist, both have posts):

```
(Category.find(2).posts | Category.find(3).posts).select(:user_id).distinct
```

This leads to:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from (irb):137:in `select'
```

My main question is why won't this work? It's fine for a single collection of categories, and returns a list of distinct user ids. When working with a merged collection, it does not. Is there something else I can try?

**End Goal:** I want to build a bigger collection of categorized posts with a loop and pull distinct users with posts that exist in those categories.

Thanks in advance!

-----------EDIT----------------

Migrations won't be much use to you.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :posts

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user    #post.user_id
    has_many :categories

end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :post        #categorization.post_id
    belongs_to :category    #categorization.category_id

end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :posts, :through=>:categorizations

end
```

Comment: Can you show the required migrations.. It will help to understand how you define models. Which in turn help us to write a query which might solve the problem.

Comment: Edited to clearly show the relations. Included the foreign keys for you. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
Category.
joins(:posts).
where(categories: {id: [1,2]}).
pluck("DISTINCT posts.user_id")
```

That is to get a `user_id` array. To get objects that have the `user_id` attribute:

```
Category.
joins(:posts).
where(categories: {id: [1,2]}).
select("posts.user_id").
distinct
```

Comment: Thanks Humza. The "|" unions the two collections. I had a syntax error in the OP but I fixed it. It should have been (Category.find(2).posts | Category.find(3).posts).

Your answer seems super close, but I can't get the users through the category. Please see the edit in the original post. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Yes that makes more sense. I've updated my answer to highlight what you want.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you use `where` instead of `find` like this:

```
Category.where(:id => [2,3]).select(:user_id).distinct
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam. Maybe I wasn't entirely clear, but the category isn't directly related to the user. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Category.pluck(:user_id).uniq
```

Comment: `.pluck("DISTINCT user_id")` would be much better.